# Gracefully jumping to next record - ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
Rails 3.2
```

I have the following in my view:

```
<% @organizations.each do |o| %>
  <% organization = Organization.find(o.organization_id)  %>
    <% if organization == nil %>
      <% next %>
    <% end %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= o.org_name %></td>
    <td><%= number_to_currency(o.revenue, :precision => 0) %></td>
    <td><%= o.rank %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

I was under the impression that if organization is not found, execution would jump to the next record. Instead, I am getting the "something went wrong".

Looking through the log file, one of the organization_id is not found in the organizations table, and that's what's triggering the error.

Why isn't execution jumping to the next record?

Temporary Solution: I changed

```
<% organization = Organization.find(o.organization_id)  %>
```

To:

```
<% organization = Organization.find_by_id(o.organization_id)  %>
```

and that gives me a nil when it does not find anything. If it's nil, the execution skips to the next record

Comment: Is your `organization_id` part of a `belongs_to` association?

Comment: organization_id  is not part of a belongs_to

Comment: Are @organizations just a bunch of Organizations? It seems weird to find something that you already have instantiated. Also, do you know about http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/exists%3F/class?

Comment: Do you say: an organization can exist in @organizations, even if it hasn't an organization_id? And if there is no organization_id, you don't want that organization evaluated in the iteration block?

Comment: @Mauddev, see my comment to Brad Werth below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find, `Organization.find(o.organization_id)` will raise an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` for the id that does not exist in the table.

Addendum:

Try something like the following:

```
<% ids = @organizations.map(&:organization_id) %>
<% organizations = Organization.where(id: ids) %>
<% organizations.each do |o| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= o.org_name %></td>
        <td><%= number_to_currency(o.revenue, :precision => 0) %></td>
        <td><%= o.rank %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

With this method, you'll fetch all the organizations with 1 query from the DB as opposed to 1 for every organization.

Comment: This will still cause the active record problem. The code I posted is not the entire logic. I need a way to recover gracefully from the RecordNotFound error

Comment: @EastsideDeveloper This code should prevent the error, by using where instead of find... It is also much more idiomatic than your example. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, I did try it. The real issue here is that it changes my code flow. There is an OrganizationPayment that the @organizations results is getting pulled from. There are instances where an organization may have deleted but its payments remain for posterity. I inherited this code and I need to fix that glitch, but... Please see how i fixed it. I am still looking for a way to recover from ActiveRecord RecordNotFound gracefully

Comment: @radhika I gave you a point for the .map suggestion. I can use it in another part of the code

Comment: The above is essentially a re-implementation of eager loading. Given a `belongs_to` association this can be done in a single DB query as well. See Rails Guides on N+1 elimination.

Comment: @D-side agreed, but the original post doesn't mention anything about a `belongs_to` association.

Comment: @radhika nah, I'm not saying your solution is bad, but the OP should note that there is a much better way if his own code were a bit different. And, btw, the same thing can be done on the database level, without involving a Ruby array. Heh, guess' I have to write my own answer .-.